# Create App Quiz Using Laravel 7 and Mysql

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to create a simple Quiz App with Laravel and Mysql .

the idea is , i'm stucked on the relattions between questions/options .

first i create a table called "quiz"

```
ID  name
1   Brazil
2   EUA
3   Japan
```

a table called "questions"

```
ID  quiz_id name
1   1   President ?
2   1   Food?
3   1   Music?
4   1   Maiority?
```

and a table called "options"

```
ID  question_id name
1   1   lula    
2   1   bolsonaro   
3   2   rice
4   2   beans
5   3   samba
6   3   rock    
7   4   black
8   4   white
```

like image below , i receive the questions related with quiz . my function on my HomeController looks like this .

```
public function index(){


    $quiz = Quiz::where('id',1)->with('questions')->get();
    $array = array('quiz' =>$quiz);




        return $array;

}
```

and my model Quiz have this relationship

```
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\quizquestion', 'quiz_id');
}
```

but i wanna make a relation of questions with options .

i'm thinking that must be another sub object inside questions . like a thirty leve .

Example :

quiz
questions
options.

because i wanna call this on my blade template , actualy i 'm calling this way

```
<body>


    @foreach($quiz as $item)

        <h1>{{$item->name}}</h1>

       @foreach($item->questions as $quest)
       <p>{{$quest->question}}</p>
        @endforeach
         @endforeach





</body>
```

that return me :

Brazil

President ?

Food ?

Music ?

Maiority?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for nested relationship query.

I assume you already setup the questions-options relationship. Here is a simplified query:

```
Quiz::with(['questions', 'questions.options'])->get();
```

or simpler (credits to @lagbox) :

```
Quiz::with('questions.options')->get();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm , i dont have a question-options relationship , but i have created and using your logic , its work . i'll try find the logical behind this . thank my friend.